# How to get my function to acknowledge a spelling mistake?

Tags: python, string, function

I have this function:

```
def is_an_oak(name): 
    """
    Returns True is name starts with 'quercus'
    >>> is_an_oak('Fagus sylvatica')
    False
    >>> is_an_oak('Quercuss petraea')
    False
    >>> is_an_oak('Quercus petraea')
    True
    >>> is_an_oak('quercus petraea')
    True
    """

    return name.lower().startswith('quercus')
```

But I need it to return "Quercuss" and any other similar spelling mistakes as False, currently it is still registering as True. I know this is because of the .startswith() method but I don't know what to replace this with in order to accept "Quercus" as the only True answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code is very close, but miss one place in the extra character after the correct word. For example: if you compare **'abc'** with '**abcd'** - what'll you will expect? *(using **startswith** method, will get True!)*  See the correction and other version to compare:

```
def is_an_oak(text):
    return text.lower().startswith( 'quercus ') # add space after the word so it can detect the extra "s"
```

```
def is_an_oak(text): 
    words = text.split()         # break text into words
    return words[0].lower() == 'quercus'  # first word
```

Running some tests:

```
words = ['Quercuss petrea', 'Quercus petrea']

for w in words:
    print(is_an_oak(w))

# Outputs:
# False
# True
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when I do >>> is_an_oak("Quercuss petraea") from the command line in python it is still registering as true

Comment: i dont know what I'm doing wrong but I've tried both of your methods and theyve both stiil came back as true. Im at a loss!

Comment: Interesting. Do you get the new `function` and not running your `old` function?  - Can you start a `new` terminal?  Or you want to copy the code and run it in https://pythontutor.com/  as a fresh new session.

Comment: Okay so I have realised my issue, when I was running ->>> is_an_oak("Quercuss petraea") it was coming back as true if I used " " marks. But is I changed to ->>> is_an_oak('Quercuss petraea') then it came back as false. However now I have another issue. This function is part of a larger script that searches for Quercus in a csv file of species names, now the full script wont run find any Quercus in the csv.

Comment: Hi, @amelia_plshelp - if you have another question, please open a new Post for it?  And if you find this helps you, please accept it now? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers